# Android - Preventing duplicate window on Intent & StartActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, launchmode

I am trying to solve an issue with my android application.

The issue is that when i start a new instance or class by calling an Intent and StartActivity, a duplicate window or view opens.

I want to keep the same activity or view but execute/run a new class without affecting the view. The intent is simply to execute an extended class but i dont want it recreating or opening a duplicate view.

I have tried using android:Launchmode="singleTop" but to no effect.

I have used the standard android navigation drawer example xml and classes. You will see the content_main.xml contains a viewswitcher which includes 2 other xml files which doesn't need to load a new instance or activity...if that makes sense.

Im not sure if the issue lies with the BeaconTracking.java where it calls the super.onCreate(...) event again maybe causing the parent view to reopen??

Any ideas where i am going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
</activity>
<activity
    android:name=".BeaconTracking"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</activity>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ...

public ViewSwitcher switcher;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

...

}


@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_vehicle_tracking) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BeaconTracking.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);

        }
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_vehicle_info) {
            //SWITCH TO BEACON SCREEN
            switcher.setDisplayedChild(2);
}

    //CLOSE NAVIGATION DRAWER WHEN BUTTON IS PRESSED
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**BeaconTracking.java**

```
public class BeaconTracking extends MainActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    switcher.setDisplayedChild(1);

}
```

**content_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewSwitcher
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/content_beacons" />

<include
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    layout="@layout/content_map" />
</ViewSwitcher>
```

Comment: Did you solve your issue? I'm struggling with something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48024740/android-activity-multiple-instance

Answer (score 0):

android:Launchmode="singleTop" will not help here, why do you want to open another activity you can manage it in your current activity with view switcher, still you want to open another activity without duplicate window. In that case you can make the transparent ui of the opening activity.

```
<activity  android:name = "BeaconTracking" 
      android:label = "@string/app_name" 
      android:theme = "@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
```

or with theme `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`

And replace the parent class to AppCompatActivity of BeaconTracking. But still BeaconTracking activity will be added in back stack.

Answer (score 0):

Each `Activity` has its own views. If you don't want to open new views, you shouldn't start a new `Activity`. Just move the functionality of your `BeaconActivity` into the `MainActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -1):

Try using android:launchMode="singleInstance" in Manifest.

Comment: In general this is a terrible idea. Special launch modes `singleInstance` and `singleTask` usually create more problems than they solve, and you need to know exactly what you are doing to use them correctly. In this case, using them will not change anything.

Comment: If we handle the activity states properly and study about singleInstance, singleTask launch modes then it will not be a problem to implement.

Comment: No, sorry. This is just wrong. This is not the correct solution. It is a workaround that usually does not work. I've corrected hundreds of people who have used these launch modes incorrectly. See any of my posts regarding launch mode. From experience I can say that using these launch modes creates more problems than it solves. But good luck!