# Android activity multiple instance

Tags: android, react-native

I'm working with React Native where I'm trying to create an independent screen that should be called when the device is locked and the app is closed.

Following is my code:

**UnlockScreenActivity.java**

```
public class UnlockScreenActivity extends ReactActivity {
// public class UnlockScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

        setContentView(R.layout...); // the xml layout

        final ReactContext reactContext = getReactInstanceManager().getCurrentReactContext();

        Button openBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.accept_call_btn);
        openBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ...
            }
        });

        Button closeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reject_call_btn);
        closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ...
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendEvent(ReactContext reactContext, String eventName, WritableMap params) {
        reactContext
        .getJSModule(DeviceEventManagerModule.RCTDeviceEventEmitter.class)
        .emit(eventName, params);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            ...
        </activity>
        ...
        <!-- none of this worked -->
        <!-- android:launchMode="singleInstance" -->
        <!-- android:launchMode="singleTask" -->
        <activity android:name=".UnlockScreenActivity" android:noHistory="true" />
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**How I call my screen:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, UnlockScreenActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP); // still the same
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); // still the same
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED); // still the same
startActivity(i);
```

After the screen opens, I see that the app has two instances:

[image]

How do I get it in a single instance?

**UPDATE**

This is how I manage and so far it's working

```
// ReactApplicationContext context
Intent i = new Intent(context, UnlockScreenActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(i);
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<activity
    android:name=".UnlockScreenActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:persistableMode="persistNever"
    android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true" />
```

Comment: this may help you FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

Comment: @vikaskumar, still tha same

Comment: @W0rmH0le, do you know anything about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this one.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
startActivity(i);
```

or you can add singletask in main activity in the root of the manifest.

```
<activity ..
      android:launchMode= "singleTask" />
```

Comment: I've stop all the process, delete the app and run all again; but still the same; #sad

Comment: please try the update answer and start your unlocksreenactivity with startActivityForResult with simple intent

Comment: Running ```Intent(context, MainActivity.class)``` it only open the main screen (react-native); is that what you expect? By the way, ```Intent i = new Intent...``` it's been called in a different class is that okay?